# Change preview time in A7R II

Tags: sony-alpha, shooting-mode

When I take a shot, the picture is displayed for a few seconds, which is too long for me. Can I change the display time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose between 10 seconds, 5 seconds or 2 seconds.

MENU → (Custom Settings) → [Auto Review] → desired setting.

[Source](http://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1520/v1/en/contents/TP0000808631.html)